# Using session_start twice

Tags: php, session

I have a pretty dumb question (I believe):

What would happen, if I were to start 2 sessions, calling `session_start()` twice? For example, I have a class `User`, where I start user's session, and a class `Error`, in which I start another session, so I can store errors and notifications in them and pass them to other pages.

Could I run into a problem, and is this efficient?

Comment: you can't start two sessions. php will throw an error saying "session already started in ...{whever first started}". You could store both classes in the same session, just under different keys.

Comment: Are you asking out of curiosity or are you looking to solve a problem you have?

Comment: I don't have a problem yet, since I've only written the User class, but as I started to work on Errors, I thought I might run into problems with sessions.

Comment: Had to downvote, because this could easily have been tested with `<?php session_start(); session_start(); ?>`

Comment: @BrianWarshaw true, but now i know the answer by opening a new tab rather than having to code an example

Comment: @nope Discovery-by-doing has always borne far more fruit (for me, at least) than discovery-by-documentation. And, at least in terms of the the expectations on this site, a person ought to try something before posting a question.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

PHP doesn't support multiple simultaneous sessions. Calling `session_start()` a second time in a request doesn't do anything unless the existing session was destroyed (via `session_destroy()`).

> `session_start()` creates a session **or resumes the current one** based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

http://php.net/session-start

Comment: Setting the session id in conjunction with session start allows to have multiple sessions in PHP. However that is not trivial. It's easier to use different session names.

Comment: @hakre is that true?  session_id must be called before session_start()  which means that you can't call session_id() a second time to switch session contexts.  calling session_id() after session_start() (I believe) would have no effect.  Even if you call session_write_close().  session_start will only `resume` the current  session.

Comment: @ajon: You can stop the session you've started and switch the ID then. no problem. But as commented, it's not trivial. Most often it's easier to change the session name.

Comment: Also point out since which PHP version this happens.

Answer (score 8):

You can use different session_start() if you check on each one if there was already a session created, in this way:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}
```

Comment: Nah you should use session_status()