# error when i call function that contain mysql connection

Tags: php, mysql

---------------conn.php-----------------

```
 <?php 

    session_start(); 

    function conn{

    $hostname = "localhost";
    $userDB = "root";
    $password = "";
    $databaseName = "forum";
$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $userDB, $password) or
            die("failed to connect");
    mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con) or
            die("failed to connect with database");

        }

            ?>
```

---------------------logindata.php------------

```
<?php 

session_start();


conn();

$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$query = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '" . $myusername . "'  and password = '" . $mypassword . "' ");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {

    echo "wrong";
} else {

    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;


    $query = mysql_query("select * from users  where username = '" . $myusername . "'  and password = '" . $mypassword . "' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=posts.php" />';
}



mysql_close($con);
?>
```

---

The error appears is (( ( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function conn() in C:\wamp\www\TechnologySociety\logindata.php on line 6
))
when i call the function

Comment: Where have you defined `conn()`?

Comment: is because you have to `session_start ` you only need one..

Comment: You either need to include conn.php in logindata.php or move `conn()` into logindata.php

Comment: @jycr753 What has that to do? It's more likely the file containing the function definition isn't included

Comment: the function conn(); is called in logindata.php // i removed session_start & nothing happend

Comment: @DamienPirsy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940443/using-session-start-twice

Comment: @jycr753 ...Aaand? does that mention repeating `session_start()` undefines functions?

Comment: you can't have two session_start other wise it will throw an error ...

Comment: `undefined function conn() in C:\wamp\www\TechnologySociety\logindata.php on line 6 ))` Is this the error you get repeating session_start()? Please, tell me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *include* conn.php in logindata.php

```
 //logindata.php
    <?php 
    ....
    include("conn.php");
    session_start();
```

You are calling session_start() twice, so that will generate another error.

You should also look at using mysqli instead of mysql

Comment: @user3136540 I really don't know why this shouldn't work, compared to the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

you only need to start the session ones -- `session_start();`
you [doc](http://www.php.net/session_start) `session_start()` creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

also don't forget to include the connection function..
`include_once('conn.php');`

Comment: Repeating session_start() has nothing to do with the error. Did you read it? `undefined function conn() in C:\wamp\www\TechnologySociety\logindata.php on line 6 ))`

Comment: @DamienPirsy yeah ... so? still he will get the error once he include the file.. are you blind or what? :P

Comment: You should solve the actual problem, not imagining another one and solving that, ignoring the rest

Answer (score 0):

---------------   logindata.php   ------------
at this line at the top of logindata.php

```
 include_once("conn.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

change

```
function conn{
```

to:

```
function conn(){
```

and return the connection at end of function

```
function conn(){

  $hostname = "localhost";
  $userDB = "root";
  $password = "";
  $databaseName = "forum";
  $con = mysql_connect($hostname, $userDB, $password) or
        die("failed to connect");
  mysql_select_db($databaseName, $con) or
        die("failed to connect with database");
  return $con;
}
```

who you should call,

```
$link = conn();
$query = mysql_query($sql, $link);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing

```
required conn.php
```

before

```
conn();
```

Also in `logindata.php` there is no need to call

```
session_start();
```

since it is already called in `conn.php` and after including it with `required()` it will be added and called

also in `conn.php` add parentheses to the function definition

```
function conn(){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code for logindata.php

```
<?php 
require('conn.php');
session_start();


conn();

$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
$query = mysql_query("select * from users where username = '" . $myusername . "'  and password = '" . $mypassword . "' ");
if (mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {

    echo "wrong";
} else {

    $_SESSION['username'] = $myusername;


    $query = mysql_query("select * from users  where username = '" . $myusername . "'  and password = '" . $mypassword . "' ");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    $_SESSION['email'] = $row['email'];

    echo '<meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; URL=posts.php" />';
}



mysql_close($con);
?>
```