# PHP: Counter using Session Variables

Tags: php, variables, session, submit, counter

I need som help adding a value to a session variable using submit buttons. If I define the variables as 0 it won't count up, and if I don't it says:

> "Notice: Undefined index: paperbagCount in
>   /home/saxon/students/20151/chwi15/www/affar3/test.php on line 52"
>
> "Notice: Undefined index: plasticbagCount in
>   /home/saxon/students/20151/chwi15/www/affar3/test.php on line 59"

```
<?php 
if(!session_status() === PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE ) {
session_start();
$_SESSION["paperbagCount"] = 0;
$_SESSION["plasticbagCount"] = 0; 
} 
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
   <title>Startsida</title>   
</head>

<body>

<?php 
if(isset($_POST['addPaper'])) {
  $_SESSION["paperbagCount"]+=1;
}

if(isset($_POST['deletePaper'])) {
    if ($_SESSION["paperbagCount"] == 0) {
        $_SESSION["paperbagCount"] == 0; 
    }else{      
    $_SESSION["paperbagCount"]-=1;
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['addPlastic'])) {
  $_SESSION["plasticbagCount"]+=1;
}

if(isset($_POST['deletePlastic'])) {
    if ($_SESSION["plasticbagCount"] == 0) {
        $_SESSION["plasticbagCount"] == 0; 
    }else{      
    $_SESSION["plasticbagCount"]-=1;
    }
}

?>  

<form method="post">
<p><label>Paperbagcount</label><br>
<input type="submit" name="addPaper" value="+">
<?php echo $_SESSION["paperbagCount"] . "\n"; ?>
<input type="submit" name="deletePaper" value="-">
</form>

<form method="post">
<p><label>Plasticbagcount</label><br>
<input type="submit" name="addPlastic" value="+">
<?php echo $_SESSION["plasticbagCount"] . "\n"; ?>
<input type="submit" name="deletePlastic" value="-">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you write session_start(); two time in you page remove below one

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940443/using-session-start-twice

Answer (score 1):

replace your PHP code by this

```
<?php 
@session_start(); // @ to avoid warning
if (!isset($_SESSION["paperbagCount"])) {
    $_SESSION["paperbagCount"] = 0;
}
if (!isset($_SESSION["plasticbagCount"])) {
    $_SESSION["plasticbagCount"] = 0;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`session_start()` creates a session or resumes the current one based on a session identifier passed via a GET or POST request, or passed via a cookie.

So remove the second `session_start()` line from the code.