# Testing PHP response in Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm making a simple registration mechanism that stores username and password into a MySQL database. How it works:

1. User enters his data into textboxes.
2. The values get fetched and validation via JQuery script.
3. If the validation is passed, an Ajax call is made to a PHP file that then checks if the Username has already been taken. If it's taken, it does `echo '0'`. If not, it does `echo '1'` and inserts the values into the database.
4. Jquery then checks the response and does an appropriate action.

   ```
   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "register.php",
       data: {usn:us, pwd: pw},
       cache: false,
       success: function(result){
           console.log(result);
           if (result=='1'){
               window.location = "next.php";
           }else{
               errorMessage= "Username taken. <br>";
               $("#regerrormsg").html(errorMessage);
           }
       }
       });
   ```

PHP:

```
include 'dbconnect.php';
    $us = $_POST["usn"];
    $pw = $_POST["pwd"];

    $tryus = $conn->query("SELECT Username from users WHERE Username='" . $us . "'");
    if ($tryus->num_rows == 0){
        echo '1';
        $conn->query("INSERT INTO users (ID, Username, Password) VALUES (DEFAULT, '" . $us . "', '" . $pw . "')");  
        session_start();
        $_SESSION["user"] = $us;
    }else{
        echo '0';
    }
```

Now, here's the weird thing. This pretty much works, except for one part. The query does indeed check if the username already exist and it does echo the appropriate value ('0' or '1'). I've tested this by logging the output in the javascript file. I've also checked my database and it never stores a duplicate user. But, for some weird reason, the `window.location = "next.php"`; is never executed, even when the value of the output is '1'. It always goes to the 'else' block.
Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: what does the console.log(response) shows?, try checking the response var type with console.log(typeof response)

Comment: As I said, it shows exactly what it should. '1' if the username is not taken, '0' if it's not. typeof(result) shows 'string'

Comment: Is this a PHP problem or a JS problem? Also, please be warned that your queries are highly vulnerable for SQL injection. Have a look at prepared statements to avoid getting hacked

Comment: Were any of the below answers helpful to you? If so, please consider selecting one as the "best answer" (click the checkmark beside the answer), and upvoting any answers that were helpful to you (UP arrow). Doing so will acknowledge the answer(s) and close out the question, which is helpful to the StackOverflow community. You receive points each time you close out a question.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to check backend responses is to use a REST Api Client. [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) is the most popular but I prefer [Insomnia](https://insomnia.rest/). Try it out, in my opinion it's a must have for front-end development.

Comment: Yeah, I'll keep that in mind for some future projects, but I'm kind of in a hurry with this one so I don't have time to learn how new stuff works.

Answer (score 0):

Please change below code:

```
if ($tryus->num_rows == 0){
    echo '1';
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO users (ID, Username, Password) VALUES (DEFAULT, '" . $us . "', '" . $pw . "')");  
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["user"] = $us;
}else{
    echo '0';
}
```

to this:

```
if ($tryus->num_rows == 0){
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO users (ID, Username, Password) VALUES (DEFAULT, '" . $us . "', '" . $pw . "')");
    echo '1';
}else{
    echo '0';
}
exit();
```

Create session in variable in next.php file.

Change `window.location = "next.php";` to `document.location.href="http://your-site-url.com/next.php";`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to things pointed out in other answers, `session_start();` should be the very first instruction, at the top of every PHP file that requires access to the $_SESSION variable.

Do not worry about calling `session_start()` in php files that do not use it - it is a bigger crime to call it too late in the file.

In particular, "To use cookie-based sessions, session_start() must be called before outputting anything to the browser."

> Every page that will use the session information on the website must be identified by the session_start() function. This initiates a session on each PHP page. The session_start function must be the first thing sent to the browser or it won't work properly. It must precede any HTML tags. Usually, the best place to position it is right after the <?php tag. It must be on every page you intend to use.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php#refsect1-function.session-start-notes

https://www.thoughtco.com/sessionstart-php-function-2694087

[What happens if you call session_start() twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12940462/1447509)

Answer (score 0):

Insomnia and Postman are great suggestions. Another great, free endpoint tester is [httpie](https://httpie.io/), which has both a GUI and a CLI option, depending on your preference.

A few things I would recommend:

1. Since you are doing an AJAX request, it’ll be easier to set your headers to `application/json` and respond with a json-encoded message. Without your full source code to review, I can’t for certain point out the issue, but it could be that because your backend is replying as html, there could be issue reading the value on the frontend.
2. Since you are using jQuery, using [$.post()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is a generally easier and more concise way of handling the request from the frontend. And if you aren’t using jQuery for much, vanilla JS has the [fetch()](https://www.topcoder.com/thrive/articles/fetch-api-javascript-how-to-make-get-and-post-requests) api, which is also pretty easy to use.
3. Please please please use [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) for MySQL queries. Leaving this unchecked and in a production environment will eventually lead to an SQL injection attack.
4. You should always be encrypting your passwords when storing them in the database. [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) is fairly easy to set up and supplied passwords can be easily checked with [password_verify()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php).